# Including a graphic in PDF with xelatex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, xelatex

I'm trying to include an image in a kableExtra table, but it will only be included if I remove the xelatex and setmainfont code from my markdown. Does anyone have a solution for this? I have tried with a jpg and png but have the same issue.

The code below compiles but the images are blank.

````
---
title: "markdownTest"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{Calibri}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=0.5in
---

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
df <- data.frame(
  stock = c('Apple','Amazon','Microsoft','Tesla'),
  value = c(300,200,150,250),
  difference = c(50,-10,20,-15)
)
df$trend <- ifelse(df$difference >0,
                   '![](Check.jpg)',
                   '![](Flag.jpg)'
                  )

kable(df, escape = F)
```
````

The below code, without xelatex, setmainfont, and \usepackage{fontspec}, works as expected.

````
---
title: "markdownTest"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
output: 
  pdf_document
geometry: margin=0.5in
---

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
df <- data.frame(
  stock = c('Apple','Amazon','Microsoft','Tesla'),
  value = c(300,200,150,250),
  difference = c(50,-10,20,-15)
)
df$trend <- ifelse(df$difference >0,
                   '![](Check.jpg)',
                   '![](Flag.jpg)'
                  )

kable(df, escape = F)
```
````

I'm trying to upload my jpg to this post but am getting an error. The flag is just a red warning exclamation, and the check is a green check. Please let me know if you need any other information, thank you.

Here is the only time the .log referencing the jpg

```
    File: """Check".jpg Graphic file (type bmp)
<"""Check".jpg>
File: """Flag".jpg Graphic file (type bmp)
<"""Flag".jpg>
File: """Check".jpg Graphic file (type bmp)
<"""Check".jpg>
File: """Flag".jpg Graphic file (type bmp)
<"""Flag".jpg>
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 175.
[1

]
```

And here are all refences to xelatex

```
Package: mathspec 2016/12/22 v0.2b LaTeX Package (Mathematics font selection fo
r XeLaTeX)
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(c:/Users/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontsp
ec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count191
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count192
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count193
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen144
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen145
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen146
```

I don't see an option to upload the whole .log, so I just tried to include the relevant parts.

Comment: Can you add the .log file for the example with the missing images?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, I updated the post. Is that information helpful? I ctrl F'd for the .jpg and xelatex. I didn't want to include the whole .log file as text and couldn't find an upload file option.

Comment: The code with xelatex, fontspec and setmainfont works fine on my computer (including the images). I have the same fontspec version as you (v2.7c). Using the TeX distribution MiKTeX v. 2.9

Comment: Do you think it could be because I’m using TeX Live? How did you save the images? I’ve read about xelatex being particular about how you save the images and their sizes, but no matter what file type or dimensions I save it as I can’t stop it from appearing blank in pdf. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I found some random images on google and saved to the .Rmd working directory. Worked fine with both .jpg and .png. Not sure about the differences between TeX Live and MiKTeX, and why this should affect your problem. Have you tried removing all other `\usepackage` except fontspec? Different versions of latex packages have strange interactions sometimes.

Comment: I just tried removing each package one at a time but no luck. I'm going to try to uninstall tinytex.